# extracting last and the second last part of url in R

Tags: r, regex, string

how can extract last part and second last part (or maybe more) parts of url and put it into the new columns?

lets say

```
mydata:
user    view
1       https://domain.ca/courses/43/pages/general-guidelines
2       https://domain.ca/courses/43/id=33/svgl11/hi/resources
3       https://domain.ca/courses/43/505/pages/detail-specification


result:
user  secondlastPart lastPart
1        pages        general-guidelines
2        hi           resources
3        pages        detail-specification
```

how can I do it in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `mydata` shown in the Note at the end we use `basename` which takes the last component together with `dirname` which takes all but the last.

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
  transmute(user, secondlastPart = basename(dirname(view)),  lastPart = basename(view))
```

giving:

```
  user secondlastPart             lastPart
1    1          pages   general-guidelines
2    2             hi            resources
3    3          pages detail-specification
```

This could alternately be done without any packages at all like this:

```
transform(mydata, secondlastPart = basename(dirname(view)),  
  lastPart = basename(view), view = NULL)
```

The third last would be `basename(dirname(dirname(view)))` and so on.

### Note

```
Lines <- "user    view
1       https://domain.ca/courses/43/pages/general-guidelines
2       https://domain.ca/courses/43/id=33/svgl11/hi/resources
3       https://domain.ca/courses/43/505/pages/detail-specification"
mydata <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
  extract(view, into = c('secondlastPart', 'lastPart'), ".*\\/(\\w+)\\/([^/]+$)")
#  user secondlastPart             lastPart
#1    1          pages   general-guidelines
#2    2             hi            resources
#3    3          pages detail-specification
```

---

The classical approach is to use `urltools`

```
library(urltools)
url_parse(df1$view)$path
```

---

In `base R`, we can use the same regex with `sub` and read using `read.table/read.csv`

```
cbind(df1['user'], read.csv(text = sub(".*\\/(\\w+)\\/([^/]+$)", 
        "\\1,\\2", df1$view), 
      header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
        col.names = c('secondlastPart', 'lastPart')))
#  user secondlastPart             lastPart
#1    1          pages   general-guidelines
#2    2             hi            resources
#3    3          pages detail-specification
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(user = 1:3, view = c("https://domain.ca/courses/43/pages/general-guidelines", 
"https://domain.ca/courses/43/id=33/svgl11/hi/resources", "https://domain.ca/courses/43/505/pages/detail-specification"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can split the string on `"/"` and store it as a list column

```
df$list_view <- strsplit(df$view, "/+")
```

and then it is easy to extract any part of the url.

Last part :

```
sapply(df$list_view, function(x) x[length(x)])
#[1] "general-guidelines"   "resources"            "detail-specification"
```

Second last part :

```
sapply(df$list_view, function(x) x[length(x) - 1])
#[1] "pages" "hi"    "pages"
```

---

We can do this in `tidyverse` as well

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
 mutate(list_view = str_split(view, "/+"), 
        last_part = map_chr(list_view, ~.x[length(.x)]), 
        second_last_part = map_chr(list_view, ~.x[length(.x) - 1]))
```

Comment: These are the cleanest solutions IMO

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function from positions of the slashes:

```
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
Fun <- function(x){
  n_slash <- str_count(x, "/")
  pattern <- paste0(rep(".*/", n_slash-1), collapse="")
  pattern1 <- paste0(pattern, "(.*)/.*", collapse="")
  pattern2 <- paste0(pattern, ".*/(.*)", collapse="")
  secondlast <- gsub(pattern1, "\\1", x)
  last <- gsub(pattern2, "\\1", x)
  return(data.frame(url=x,secondlast=secondlast, last=last))
}
# execute the function and bind the results in a dataframe
extracted <- rbindlist(lapply(urls, Fun))
extracted
    1:       https://domain.ca/courses/43/pages/general-guidelines      pages   general-guidelines
    2:      https://domain.ca/courses/43/id=33/svgl11/hi/resources         hi            resources
    3: https://domain.ca/courses/43/505/pages/detail-specification      pages detail-specification
```